# Nonlinear least square optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-programming

## Problem description

Given data at many time instance $t$,

$$\min _{\alpha, \Lambda, \beta} \lVert y(t) - \alpha e^{\Lambda t} \beta \rVert_F$$
with $$ \lVert \alpha \rVert_2^F = 1 $$

where $y(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times M}$, $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$ is a diagonal matrix, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times M}$

## Special case

if $\alpha = I$, the problem becomes a classical problem in **variable projection for nonlinear least square**, which has been studied for decades.

The benefit of $\alpha = I$ is that, the nonlinear and linear part becomes separable through pseudo-inverse.

## What I currently do

I can simply (blindly) use an optimization package to **generally solve** this problem by do naive gradient descent, it looks like a neural network training process, without leveraging the structure of the problem.

**It works for toy problem, like when n,r less than 3.**

The downside is that, since it doesn't assume any structure to leverage, the computational time is costly.

## What I want to know

I want to know if any one know which category does this problem belongs to, and if there is better algorithm existing to solve this.

Comment: What is the description of $\xi$?

Comment: @nicoguaro Sorry. It should be $\Lambda$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to problems solved with filter diagonalization.

[https://www.chem.uci.edu/~mandelsh/publ/review.pdf](https://www.chem.uci.edu/%7Emandelsh/publ/review.pdf)

[https://www.chem.uci.edu/~mandelsh/publ/cross_JTCC.pdf](https://www.chem.uci.edu/%7Emandelsh/publ/cross_JTCC.pdf)

https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0204049.pdf

so you can perhaps adapt this technique to your particular problem.